# Number of AP sequence - using Van Der Waerden

Tags: combinatorics

We know using Van Der Waerden theorem, that for any $n$ large enough, $n>W(k,r)$, any $r$-coloring $\chi : [n]\rightarrow [r]$ will contains a monochromatic $k$-arithmetic progression.

I want to prove the following additional result.

> For $n$ large enough, any $r$-coloring $\chi : [n]\rightarrow [r]$ will contains at least $c(k,r)n^2$ monochromatic $k$-arithmetic progression.

I started by defining first the list of all $W-AP$ in $[n]$(given their start point $a$ and the difference $d$), and we can use the theorem to prove that each one contains a $k$-AP.

Now if for each one of these $k$-AP we can bound the number of $W$-AP where it may appear, by $O(n^2)$ we will be done by some additional counting argument.

Any idea how this can be proven?

Comment: Have you answreed it yet?

Comment: Yes I did. I need to look for it in my notes. I'll post an answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

I present the proof in bullets:

- As you stated we first count the number of $W$-AP's in $[n]$ and we find that this number is $\Omega(N^{2})$, i.e. at least $c(k,r)N^{2}$ for sufficiently large $N$.
- Next observe that van der Waerden's Theorem implies that each one of the aforementioned $W$-AP's contains a $k$-arithmetic progression.
- Now, to correct any overcounting we divide the number by $\binom{W}{2}$, as there are at most that much ways for a $k$-AP to be in a $W$-AP.

Hence, the number of $k$-AP's in $[n]$ is at least $\frac{c(k,r)}{\binom{W}{2}}N^{2}$.

This proof by for $3$-AP's can be found in the 1988 paper of Frankl,Graham and Rödl,
Quantitative Theorems for regular systems of Equations.